# Add vue directive in custom directive in Nuxt3

Tags: vuejs3, nuxt3

is there any way in nuxt3 to add in a custom directive vue directive ?

I want to add v-if="false" to element if special argument in my directive will be false.
I tried this code but id doesn't work

```
export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
  nuxtApp.vueApp.directive('auth', {
    beforeMount(el, binding, vnode) {
      // Создаем новый объект директивы v-if
      const vIfDirective = {
        name: 'if',
        value: false,
      };

      // Добавляем созданную директиву в массив директив у vnode
      vnode.dirs.push(vIfDirective);

      // Применяем директиву v-if к элементу el
      const directives = vnode.data.directives || [];
      directives.push({
        name: 'if',
        value: false,
        expression: 'false',
        arg: null,
        modifiers: {},
      });
      vnode.data.directives = directives;
    },
  });
});
```